# Create downloadable file in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, download

Visiting the page

```
localhost:3000/download_me
```

calls the controller action download_me in controller foo.

```
class foo < ApplicationController
  def download_me
    # a file is created here i.e. temp.csv in directory C:\
  end
end
```

The controller shall create a temporary csv file and after that trigger a download in the browser that is visiting the page.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Is there any reason you want to store the temp file on your server? If so something like this should suffice (using [fastercsv](http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/), which you'll need to install):

```
require 'fastercsv'
FILE_PATH= "root/to/tmpfile.csv"

FasterCSV.open(FILE_PATH, "w") do |csv|
    csv << 'add some data'
end

send_file file_path, :type=>'text/csv'
```

I suggest you probably don't need to store the file though so just replace the FasterCSV.open line with:

```
csv = FasterCSV.generate do |csv|
```

Then spit out the csv as the response:

```
send_data csv, :type=> 'text/csv'
```

Comment: I ended up using 'send_data' instead of 'send_file' for this. I don't know if it's necessary but because I had a data stream rather than a file, I didn't have to mess with disk I/O, etc.

Comment: That's probably the best to do. Modified answer for future reference

Comment: You don't need to install FasterCSV in most cases. In ruby 1.9.2 the default 'CSV' is FasterCSV, in ruby 1.8.7 FasterCSV is included.